# Send Email from approval task form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, infopath, sharepoint-online, approval-process

In my reusable workflow, I have added an approval action. Everything works perfectly.
What I want is - When approver comes to approval form, he should be able to send notification email to the initiator (From that form) that he has started working on that document.

What I have tried - 
I have added a button clicking on which will submit the form to initiator.
Screenshot:
[image]

But it fails.
possible reason - when I create a data connection in workflow's infopath form to submit form as email, I am getting following warning
[image]

I also tried to update status field and wait for it to changes in workflow and send an email from sp designer workflow. it didn't work.

Please help or suggest any other possible way to achieve this functionality (Send Email from approval task form to initiator).